# Which is grammatically correct/ appropriate? Help. Just want to use the one that is good to hear

Tags: grammar

I keep one from every bouquet Jonathan has ever brought me. OR I kept one from every bouquet Jonathan had given me.

Comment: It depends - are you still keeping them or not, and has Jonathan stopped bringing them, or does he still bring them?

Answer (score 0):

I keep one flower from every bouquet Jonathan **brings me.**